# Inductive set, maximal elements and upper bounds

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory

In my algebra notes :

**Definition of upper bound**

$x \in X$ is an upper bound of $Y$ if $y \le x\ \ \forall y \in Y$.

**Definition of maximal element**

We say $m \in X $ is a maximal element if $m\leqslant x\ \forall \in X\ \implies x=m$

**Definition of inductive set**

Let $X$ be a set and $\le $ an ordering over $X$

$X$ is said to be inductive if any subset $Y \subset X$ , $Y$ totally ordered has a least an upper bound in $X$

Then they give a couple of examples I don't understand:

1. Any finite set has maximal elements and it is partially ordered and inductive, for any ordering defined over it.
2. $\Bbb N, \Bbb Z,\Bbb Q,\Bbb R$, with the usual ordering, are not inductive

Can someone explain or prove why?

In 1) how can I be sure this is valid for any ordering?

In 2) If I considered any finite set in any of these sets, with the usaul ordering, it has to be totally ordered an therefore the greatest one would be an upper bound and hence, inductive. I don't get why they say they are not inductive .

Comment: At least an upper bound, or a least upper bound?

Comment: at least: one or more

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver, I have one question  You have a statement _We say $m\in X$ is a maximal element if_, now I expected a condition in form of an implication, e. g., _We say... if_*** sth**$\implies$**sth**, but I feel like your _if_ already is a part of $\implies$. I wanted to edit your question, so could you let me know if something is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\langle A,\le\rangle$ is a non-empty finite partial order, let $X$ be a totally ordered subset of $A$. $X$ is finite, so we can list its elements as $X=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. Moreover, since $X$ is totally ordered by $\le$, we can index its elements so that $x_1\le x_2\le\ldots\le x_n$. But then $x_n$ is an upper bound for $X$, so $A$ is inductive.

To see that $A$ has maximal elements, let $a_1$ be any element of $A$. If $a_1$ is not maximal, there is some $a_2\in A$ such that $a_1<a_2$. If $a_2$ is not maximal, there is some $a_3\in A$ such that $a_2<a_3$. Keep going; $A$ is finite, so the process must stop after some finite number of steps, and at that point we have a maximal element of $A$. (This argument even shows that if $a_1$ is any element of $A$ whatsoever, $A$ has a maximal element $m$ such that $a_1\le m$.)

$\Bbb N$ is a totally ordered subset of $\Bbb N$, $\Bbb Z$, $\Bbb Q$, and $\Bbb R$ that has no upper bound, so none of these four sets is inductive.

Comment: X is not totally ordered, there is an ordering defined on it which is in general a partial ordering, then if for any subset Y that happens to be totally ordered I can find at least one upper bound, X is called inductive. Sorry if my using <= made you think so

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver: No, you misread my answer. In my answer $A$ is the partially ordered set; $X$ is some subset of it that happens to be totally ordered by $\le$. In other words, my $A$ is the $X$ of your comment, and my $X$ is the $Y$ of your comment.

Comment: Jeez!, you are right my bad. In the second paragraph, how can you know some element of A has to be a maximal element? Since you are going over the elements of A, which is partially ordered you could run into non-comparable elements you can't even compare. Isn't it possible that no element is maximal?

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver: No, it’s not possible. Start with any $a_1\in A$. If there is any $x\in A$ such that $a_1<x$, pick one and call it $a_2$. If there is any $x\in A$ such that $a_2<x$, pick one and call it $a_3$. Keep going in this fashion. At each step you’re picking an element of $A$ different from all of the ones that you’ve already picked, so the process has to stop at some point: $A$ has only finitely many different elements. But there’s only one way for it to stop: for some $a_n$ there is no $x\in A$ such that $x_n<x$. And that is exactly what it means for $a_n$ to be maximal in $A$.

Comment: just a typo:  it should be $a_n \le x$ in the next-to-last sentence of your comment

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver: It should indeed; thanks!